# Ubuntu 14.04 live usb won't boot, seems incompatible with nouveau

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, live-usb, nouveau

So it's seems to be a fairly common problem that ubuntu live usbs won't run because they lack the necessary nvidia drivers. I have a geforce gtx 960 and when I try to run the live usb I see a lot of nouveau errors. I have a couple of questions:

Is there an older version of ubuntu that doesn't have this issue?
Is there a way to try out just the terminal from the live usb and install the necessary drivers on a persistent image and then try the install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from the Ubuntu installation USB media you already have created.

Select (highlight) **Try Ubuntu without installing** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the **end of the linux line**.
Then press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key for booting into the Ubuntu Live desktop.

Now you can explore Ubuntu - when you decide to install Ubuntu, do the same when booting the system for the first time. After having installed the NVIDIA drivers, this is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up installing 12.04 for now because there seems to be less of a compatability issue, but this is good to know in the future.